Run an application as administrator on system startup without user intervention
I need to configure a Windows machine to run an application with administrative privileges each time the system starts, without prompting the user for elevation.
I understand that normally, the Task Scheduler or scripting methods might be used for such tasks, but I am looking for a solution that involves only modifications to the Windows Registry or file system settings.
Is there a way to achieve this using just registry keys or file modifications?

Can you explain why not a scheduled task? The only other real options are to use startup-script group policies (can be done with just registry entries, but it's awkward) or register it as a windows service (probably not what you want). It's almost always easier to create a scheduled task with schtasks /create [...], depending on what you need

Because I want to add the app to the pc without starting the main os

Running/installing an application requires starting the OS. If this is like an imaging/template use case, you can add startup scripts to separate sysprep passes for first time boot or something

The easiest solution is definitely to use Task Scheduler, and use the user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM to run your task at computer startup.
It is easy to setup and given that you can run the task as the user that created the task, you can also test that it works.
But if you really don't want to use Task Scheduler, you can install software that creates a service of any program, and then configure the service to automatically start.
These are your two options. Placing a file somewhere to autostart or adding a registry entry to autostart will always start at user login under the user's scope.
Group Policy could be used with a startup script (not login script) from Computer Management, that will also run as system without user interaction, but you need a domain controller or pro version of windows, and you did not specify that you have that, so its unlikely that you could.
